# how can I make a dictionary with an exact key order in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, key, unordered

I want to make a dictionary with a specific set of keys and a specific set of values. These are the keys I want to use:

```
k = ['date', 'deviceCategory', 'transactionId', 'productSku', 'productName', 'productCategoryHierarchy', 'channelGrouping', 'itemRevenue', 'itemQuantity']
```

And these are the values for each key:

```
v = [datetime.date(2019, 3, 5), 'desktop', 1551740677701, 60104621, '(not set)', 'sale/apartment/alicante/bajo-vinalopo/elx', 'Tráfico de Búsqueda de Pago - Venta', 0.0, 1]
```

If I use a set or try to make a dictionary using this:

```
d = dict(zip(k, v))
```

Or even this (what I really intend to do):

```
d = dict(zip(map(lambda x: "ga_%s" % x, k), v))
```

I get this:

```
{'ga_itemRevenue': 0.0, 'ga_itemQuantity': 1, 'ga_deviceCategory': 'desktop', 'ga_date': datetime.date(2019, 3, 5), 'ga_channelGrouping': 'Tráfico de Búsqueda de Pago - Venta', 'ga_productSku': 60104621, 'ga_productName': '(not set)', 'ga_productCategoryHierarchy': 'sale/apartment/alicante/bajo-vinalopo/elx', 'ga_transactionId': 1551740677701}
```

I know key order is not relevant in python dictionaries (at least, the ones made with `dict()`) but I need the keys and their matching values to form the dictionary in the exact same order, which is not alphabetical. Just... the same key order.

I've tried making an ordered dictionary with `collections.OrderedDict()` and the order is the one I want except for the fact it gives me a list of tuples. I've also tried to kind of 'convert' the ordered dictionary into a regular one with this:

```
d = json.loads(json.dumps(x))
```

But it gives me an error because the `datetime` object cannot be serialized (or so it says the error message) and I need it like that (as a `datetime` object) as this is going to be written to a database table with the `cx_Oracle` package.

I've also read about `frozenset()` but seems like I need a previously existing set to 'freeze' it and once I create a set is exactly like trying to make a dictionary. keys are sprayed over the set and I need them in the same order they're declared in the keys array.

How can I achieve this?

**#EDIT 1. I forgot to say this is done in Python 2.7.x**

**#EDIT 2. Here is the code fragment I'm having problems with:**

```
reports = response.get("reports", [])

if len(reports) > 0:
  for report in reports:
    rows = report.get("data", {}).get("rows", [])

    if len(rows) > 0:
      k = ga_dimensions + ga_metrics
      o = []

      for row in rows:
        o.append(map(lambda x, y: cast_field_type(x, y), row.get("dimensions", []) + row.get("metrics", [])[0]["values"], k))

      if len(o) > 0:
         # insert all data rows into the table
         for v in o:
           for i in range(0, len(v)):
             if k[i] == "date" and is_date(v[i]):
               v[i] = date(*map(int, v[i].split("-")))
             elif isinstance(v[i], unicode):
               v[i] = v[i].encode("utf-8")

           v = dict(zip(map(lambda x: "ga_%s" % x, k), v))
           cr.execute(q, v)

         # commit all changes
         db.commit()
```

This script fetches data from Google Analytics (using the v4 API), infer the appropiate data types (for database storage with Oracle) from the first row of data, traverse the data rows so specific fields (dates and Unicode strings, basically) get appropiately casted/converted/encoded before being sent to the database and, when done that, commit the changes so the data gets written for real.

I try to do this because the script gives me this error when trying to supply the dictionary per se:

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER
```

And this is because the data is being supplied with a key order that is different from the SQL INSERT query being specified.

Comment: Prior to Python 3.7, a `dict` would not preserve any information about the order in which key/value pairs were added. Use `collections.OrderedDict` instead. The issue of preserving a `datetime` object across JSON encoding/decoding is an entirely separate problem, though.

Comment: It's only the representation of an `OrderedDict` that looks like a list of tuples.

Comment: OrderedDict behaves exactly like a dict , what are you trying to do with it that makes it not behave like one?

Answer (score 1):

`collections.OrderedDict` seems to do what you want. To illustrate what @chepner mentioned about the representation of `OrderedDict` being tuples, I'll show you what I ran:

```
#encoding: utf-8
from collections import OrderedDict
import datetime

k = ['date', 'deviceCategory', 'transactionId', 'productSku', 'productName', 'productCategoryHierarchy', 'channelGrouping', 'itemRevenue', 'itemQuantity']
v = [datetime.date(2019, 3, 5), 'desktop', 1551740677701, 60104621, '(not set)', 'sale/apartment/alicante/bajo-vinalopo/elx', 'Tráfico de Búsqueda de Pago - Venta', 0.0, 1]

d = OrderedDict(zip(k,v))
for i in d:
  print('{}: {}'.format(i,d[i]))

print('\n\n')

print(d)
```

and this was the output:

```
date: 2019-03-05
deviceCategory: desktop
transactionId: 1551740677701
productSku: 60104621
productName: (not set)
productCategoryHierarchy: sale/apartment/alicante/bajo-vinalopo/elx
channelGrouping: Tráfico de Búsqueda de Pago - Venta
itemRevenue: 0.0
itemQuantity: 1



OrderedDict([('date', datetime.date(2019, 3, 5)), ('deviceCategory', 'desktop'), ('transactionId', 1551740677701), ('productSku', 60104621), ('productName', '(not set)'), ('productCategoryHierarchy', 'sale/apartment/alicante/bajo-vinalopo/elx'), ('channelGrouping', 'Tr\xc3\xa1fico de B\xc3\xbasqueda de Pago - Venta'), ('itemRevenue', 0.0), ('itemQuantity', 1)])
```

So it looks like it's behaving as you were trying to get it to.

Answer (score 1):

The above solution might be what you need, but if you used pandas you'd get an intermediate dataframe which makes manipulating, analyzing, and visualizing data easier (if that's an avenue you wanted). The solution looks something like this:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

k = ['date', 'deviceCategory', 'transactionId', 'productSku', 'productName', 'productCategoryHierarchy', 'channelGrouping', 'itemRevenue', 'itemQuantity']

v = [datetime.date(2019, 3, 5), 'desktop', 1551740677701, 60104621, '(not set)', 'sale/apartment/alicante/bajo-vinalopo/elx', 'Tráfico de Búsqueda de Pago - Venta', 0.0, 1]

df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(v, k)], axis=1)

# the dataframe
date                                                     2019-03-05
deviceCategory                                              desktop
transactionId                                         1551740677701
productSku                                                 60104621
productName                                               (not set)
productCategoryHierarchy  sale/apartment/alicante/bajo-vinalopo/elx
channelGrouping                 Tráfico de Búsqueda de Pago - Venta
itemRevenue                                                       0
itemQuantity                                                      1

dict = df.to_dict()
results = dict[0]
results

# the dictionary
{'date': datetime.date(2019, 3, 5),
 'deviceCategory': 'desktop',
 'transactionId': 1551740677701,
 'productSku': 60104621,
 'productName': '(not set)',
 'productCategoryHierarchy': 'sale/apartment/alicante/bajo-vinalopo/elx',
 'channelGrouping': 'Tráfico de Búsqueda de Pago - Venta',
 'itemRevenue': 0.0,
 'itemQuantity': 1}
```

Comment: using Pandas is an option for me so... I'm going to try it. Thank you very much for your suggestion :)

Comment: Demons! I must be doing something really nasty with the data or it's the pre-processing of each column what's tampering with the dictionary because... I get exactly the same result as with `dict(zip(map(lambda x: "ga_%s" % x, k), v))` :S

Answer (score 0):

Two important things to note:

- make sure you use bind variables (for performance and security).
  This will also let you name the variables so the data order shouldn't
  matter
- when inserting lots of rows it is MUCH more efficient to
  use `executeMany()` as discussed in
  https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/efficient-and-scalable-batch-statement-execution-in-python-cx_oracle